# Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks how to add refernce to project

Tags: winforms, msdn, powerpacks

I've added PowerPacks from MSDN, but I don't have a clue how to add it to my winform project.
what should I looking for in COM tab (in Add reference)?
I saw on some other forms that I need to search for the dll in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\VBPowerPacks\en".. but as you can guess I find nothing.
*I know for sure that I did actually installed it because I can see it "Add/Remove Programs".

Please your help :)

Amit.

Comment: please Don't put tags in the name.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand.